# Angular-Material2: Align text and md-icon vertically to match vertical style?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I know I am probably missing something here. I am trying to align md-icon and some text vertically, right now the word "sample text" displays below the icon.

```
<div>
  <md-icon>home</md-icon> Sample Text
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

I did try playing around with vertical align on the Sample Text using a span but couldn't get anything working and felt kind of hacky anyway.

Anyone know how to get this effect?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is a common issue when using `<md-icon>`. To align the icon and text, you can put your text inside a span and apply style to that:

```html
<div>
  <md-icon>home</md-icon><span class="aligned-with-icon">Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

**In your component.css:**

```css
.aligned-with-icon{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px; /* optional */
}
```

You can also use `relative` position if you'll be putting multiple icons in the same div. Here is the css for that:

```css
.aligned-with-icon-relative{
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    margin-left: 5px; /* optional */
}
```

---

Another option is to use `flex` display on the outer div and `align-items` to `center`:

**In your html:**

```html
<div class="with-icon">
  <md-icon>home</md-icon>Sample Text
</div>
```

**In your css:**

```css
.with-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

---

Here is a [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/I8iRAvAhN0pwgPrPVZx3?p=preview)

Comment: The last one worked for me using: <a href='mailto:{{ theEmail }}' class="with-icon"><i class="material-icons">email</i><span>{{ theEmail }}</span></a>

Answer (score 30):

I utilize the `inline` attribute.  This will cause the icon to correctly scale with the size of the button.

```html
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon inline=true>local_movies</mat-icon>
      Movies
    </button>

    <!-- Link button -->
    <a mat-flat-button color="accent" routerLink="/create"><mat-icon inline=true>add</mat-icon> Create</a>
```

I add this to my `styles.css` to:

- solve the vertical alignment problem of the icon inside the button
- material icon fonts are always a little too small compared to button text

```css
button.mat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-raised-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-flat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-stroked-button .mat-icon {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Comment: I vouch for using the `inline` attribute and `vertical-align: bottom`

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or

```css
span {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using CSS flexbox

```
<!-- HTML part -->

<div class="outer-div">
 <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
 <span>Home</span>
</div>

<!-- CSS part -->
.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.outer-div > span {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I must say such a simple thing should automatically work out of the box.
But you can use `position: absolute` to center icon vertically as follow:

You can find a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1kc6bp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-types-example.css) here

```
button {
  /* manually making space for mat-icon because
    mat-icon is not position: absolute
  */
  padding-left: 30px; 
}
::ng-deep .mat-icon{
    font-size: 16px !important; /*change this as per your needs*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-22px, -50%);

    /*centering image inside mat-icon box*/
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```